# naming variables from string

Tags: python-3.x, variables

mabe I'm asking for too much, but, is there possibility to create variable for instantiating class with name from another string variable?

something like this:

```
 name = 'my_class_instance' # string variable holding name

 my_class_instance = my_cool_class(arg1, arg2, arg3)  #instance of a class in variable with name from string
```

br,
Ivica

Comment: Possible? yes. But unless you have a very good reason to do so, it's a bad idea. Most cases where someone thinks they need dynamically named variables are better served by using the right data types such as dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to say it is very-very dangerous and not recommended to do that.

But you can do it with `exec` function. [You can find more info about it on this page.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec)

I have written a representative code for you.

**Code:**

```
name = "my_class_instance"


class MyCoolClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def print_args(self):
        print(self.arg1)
        print(self.arg2)
        print(self.arg3)


exec(
    "{var_name} = MyCoolClass({arg1}, {arg2}, {arg3})".format(
        var_name=name, arg1="'test_1'", arg2="'test_2'", arg3="'test_3'"
    )
)

my_class_instance.print_args()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
test_1
test_2
test_3
```